# How to write specification for equalignorecase using criteria builder

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

Currently, I am unable to retrieve the results if the name is Case insensitive search with Predicate and Criteria API.

sample code :

in the request, I am passing `"beneficiaryName": "sample Telecommunications Plc"`.

in database record stored as `beneficiaryName= "Sample Telecommunications Plc"`.

in impl class:

```java
SearchUtils.checkNullOrEmptyString(searchinput.getBeneficiaryName())
                        ? null : AwardSpecificationUtils.beneficiaryName(searchinput.getBeneficiaryName().trim()));
```

Specification class:

```java
public static Specification<AwardDemo> beneficiaryName(String beneficiaryName) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(root.get("beneficiary").get("beneficiaryName"),"%beneficiaryName%"));
    }
```

I am not getting the results because of Case insensitivity.

Could you please help me with how to search for equalignorecase using Specifications?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `CriteriaBuilder::lower` method

```java
public static Specification<AwardDemo> beneficiaryName(String beneficiaryName) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> 
        cb.like(
            cb.lower(root.get("beneficiary").get("beneficiaryName")), 
            cb.lower(cb.literal("%" + beneficiaryName + "%"))
        );
}
```